# PhpStorm showing SVN instead of real folder names

Tags: svn, ide, phpstorm

I have a repo on SVN. When opening PhpStorm for the first time, instead of seeing folder names as they are, I am seeing this:

[image: img]

Problem is sometimes resolved by restarting the IDE, or by flushing the auth cache and restarting again...but the issue is getting really annoying. Is there any way to make it work like it should?

Comment: The project view seems to be severely modified. Does it also happen the same way after you disable all custom plugins (Settings | Plugins | Installed | Downloaded), invalidate the caches and restart again?

Comment: I have installed SVNToolbox plugin. Disabling it seems to resolve the issue. Thanks